# C# .NET Design Pattern issue

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns

I'm trying to implement the best code re-usability. The problem is that I can't access the base method located in the Base Abstract class form the Main Program through the repository.

If you go through the example below you will see a sample code of my situation.

So my question is how can I access methods located in the base abstract class from the main program.

Classes/Interfaces

```
public abstract class BaseEntity
{
    public override abstract String ToString();
}

public abstract class BaseClass<T> where T : BaseEntity
{
    public T GetById(int id)
    {
        //Dummy Code
        return new T();
        //
    }
}

public interface IFooRepository
{
    IList<Foo> GetOrderedObjects();
}

public interface FooRepository : BaseClass<Foo>, IFooRepository
{
    public IList<Foo> GetOrderedObjects()
    {
        //GetById method is accessible from the repository - Fine
        var obj = this.GetById(5);

        //Dummy Code
        return new List<Foo>();
        //
    }
}
```

//Main App

```
public class void Main()
{
    private IFooRepository _fooRepository;

    public void ProgramStartsHere()
    {
         //This is ok.
         var list = _fooRepository.GetOrderedObjects();

         //Problem is here - GetById method is not accessible from the main program through the FooRepository
         var obj = _fooRepository.GetById(10);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that your code is OK? I mean that interface with implemented method is wrong. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87d83y5b(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: public interface FooRepository : BaseClass<Foo> how this can compile ? you can't derive an interface from a class

Answer (score 10, accepted):

GetById isn't defined in the interface

I would make an

```
public interface IBaseRepository<T> where T : BaseEntitiy {
 T GetById<T>(int id);
}
```

Then `BaseClass` implements `IBaseRepository<T>`

and `IFooRepository` inherits from `IBaseRepository<Foo>`

EDIT :

A full example, similar to @Olivier J-D one, with idea (maybe wrong), that GetOrderedObject may be same for all your entities.

```
public abstract class BaseEntity
{
    public override abstract String ToString();
}

//all generic methods
public interface IRepositoryBase<T>
    where T : BaseEntity, new()
{
    T GetById(int id);
    IList<T> GetOrderedObjects();

}

//all methods specific to foo, which can't be in a generic class
public interface IFooRepository :IRepositoryBase<Foo>
{
    void Update(Foo model);
}

//implementation of generic methods
public abstract class BaseClass<T> : IRepositoryBase<T>
    where T : BaseEntity, new() // ===> Add new() constraint here
{
    public T GetById(int id)
    {
        return new T();
    }
    public IList<T> GetOrderedObjects() {
        var obj = this.GetById(5);

        //Dummy Code
        return new List<Foo>();
        //
    }
}

//implementation of Foo specific methods
public class FooRepository : BaseClass<Foo>, IFooRepository
{
    public void Update(Foo model) {
    //bla bla
    }
}
```

Comment: I second that answer! This is the way I want to do it.. clean and reduce redundant code..

Comment: Do you have a full example? Cause i got confused :/

Comment: Done, or look @Olivier one, they both can be used, depending on your specific needs...

Answer (score 4):

Add a new Interface which declares the `GetById` method and let `IFooRepository` and `BaseClass<T>` inherit from it. You will have to add a generic type parameter to `IFooRepository` as well. (I renamed `IFooRepository` to `IRepository<T>`, since it is generic now.)

```
public abstract class BaseEntity
{
    public override abstract String ToString();
}

public interface IRetriever<T>
    where T : BaseEntity, new()
{
    T GetById(int id);
}

public interface IRepository<T> : IRetriever<T>
    where T : BaseEntity, new()
{
    IList<T> GetOrderedObjects();
}

public abstract class BaseClass<T> : IRetriever<T>
    where T : BaseEntity, new() // ===> Add new() constraint here
{
    public T GetById(int id)
    {
        return new T();
    }
}

public class FooRepository : BaseClass<Foo>, IRepository<Foo>
{
    public IList<Foo> GetOrderedObjects()
    {
        var obj = this.GetById(5);
        return new List<Foo>();
    }
}
```

This will work fine then

```
IRepository<Foo> _fooRepository = new FooRepository();
var list = _fooRepository.GetOrderedObjects();
var obj = _fooRepository.GetById(10);
```

Comment: Nice one... But one remark : what's the interest of two separate interfaces in your example ? If all is generic, IList<T> GetOrderedObjects() should be in IRetriever<T>, no ? and GetOrderedObject should be in BaseClass<T> as it's also generic ?

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus: A separate interface makes sense, since `BaseClass<T>` implements `GetById`. Although it would work without it. If `IRepository<T>` declared `GetById` directly, `FooRepository` would automatically implement it by inheriting it from `BaseClass<T>`. However, it appears cleaner to me like this.

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus: It was user1382086's decision to implement `GetById` in `BaseClass<T>` and `GetOrderedObject` in `FooRepository`. Probably because he has several repositories that can inherit the same implementation of `GetById` but need to implement different `GetOrderedObjects` methods.

Comment: That make sense, thx for argument. But "avocat du diable", why do you make it generic, then ?

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus: Simply because `GetById` has a generic return type of `T`.

Comment: I'll stop annoying you after that, but this was clear, I was speaking of IRepository<T>, not IRetriever<T>. I mean wether GetOrderedObjects is really "class specific", and then it should be in an non generic repo, or it's not, and then it should be in the IRetriever<T>, or it's "partially specific", and I wouldn't call the interface IRepository. Mais j'en* les mouches...

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus: Either you declare `interface IFooRepository : IRetriever<Foo>` or `interface IRepository<T> : IRetriever<T>`. The second option is a more universal approach. In the first case you would have to declare a new interface for every type of repository. Si tu comprend ce que je veux dire.

Comment: oh yeah, I understand now that I've been really stupid on this one, mixing generic interface declaration and concrete implementation. C'est bien mieux, mes excuses ;)

Answer (score 3):

Your `_fooRepository` inherits from `IFooRepository`, not `FooRepository`, so it doesn't have access to `GetById(10);`

Answer (score 3):

You must expose the `GetById` method in your repository interface.

```
public interface IFooRepository
{  
    IList<Foo> GetOrderedObjects();
    Foo GetById(int id);
}
```

Alternatively you can use a type parameter constraint, as stated by Raphaël Althaus

Comment: replace T by Foo, not Foo by T ;)

Answer (score -3):

IFooRepository doesn't inherit from BaseClass, so you have to cast _fooRepository to FooRepository. Then you can access GetById()

Answer (score -5):

Cast it to the base class.

```
var obj = ((BaseClass<Foo>)_fooRepository).GetById(10);
```

Comment: Casting is always a bad idea - in most cases using it shows that your OOP structure is wrong..